# Change behavior of clicking author name

Tags: ide, rider

After update `2020` -> `2022`, behavior of clicking author name has been changed.
On 2020, clicking author name (red box) showed me `git -> show history` popup.
But after update, it is just button for toggle `git blame`
Can I change this behavior to previous one?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two types of actions available after clicking the author name in the `Code Vision`:

1. Annotations
2. History

You can right click the name then go to `Configuration` and set it up to display `History`

[image: Settings snapshot]